# How to share a jupyterlab project that's linked with sagemaker?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, amazon-sagemaker

I have a notebook instance on AWS SageMaker that I'd like to be able to share with colleagues and have them make edits to the code and be able to run tests themselves using the AWS compute that I have setup on my account.

Is this possible? And if so, how? Everywhere I look, I see people saying that you can share a project with sagemaker studio, but all I'm working with is jupyterlab.

Comment: You findings are correct, you can share sagemaker studio notebooks, pipelines or projects.

Answer (score 1):

Basesd on your comments I assume you are using a Classic SageMaker Notebook Instance and not SageMaker Studio. SageMaker Studio has the ability to share notebooks to other users in your domain. Please see this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/notebooks-sharing.html) for more information.

If you would like to share a notebook from a Classic SageMaker Notebook instance you could download it manually and share it with your colleagues.

You do have the ability to create a pre-signed URL for your SageMaker Notebook instance. Once this URL is generarted anyone who has access to it can access your Notebook Instance and collaborate on your notebook.
That being said, it is important to note that the URL gives access to the whole SageMaker Notebook Instance and anyone who does have it has access all your data/files.

Kindly see the [`CreatePresignedNotebookInstanceUrl`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sagemaker/create-presigned-notebook-instance-url.html) documentation for more information.

Moreover, you can call this API and create the URL using the [AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sagemaker/create-presigned-notebook-instance-url.html)